# Returning enchantment on a creature

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

I have a feat that allows me to pick up and throw another creature as if it were a thrown weapon. The *greater belt of mighty hurling* item from *Pathfinder*, among other things, allows me to apply *returning* to any weapon I throw, provided I am proficient with it.

The *returning* property states that the weapon flies back to me before my next turn. However, in the case of a thrown creature, that means it gets its own turn while it is in the middle of flying back to me. How does this affect its turn?

Comment: How on Oerth have you become proficient at throwing monsters?

Comment: Look, the idea is fundamentally crazy enough that you just need to work things out with your DM.  It's well beyond the RAW.  :)  There *is* a feat in Races of Stone that lets you throw allies, btw -- but no word on putting weapon properties on them!

Comment: It's always the psychotic things that turn out awesome.

Comment: Those feats don't deal damage because they don't need to. D&D 3.5e has [falling damage rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#falling). You can't throw a person off a cliff and have them take no damage, because they would fall and hit the ground. If someone is thrown high enough, the falling damage rules take over. Interpret them loosely if you want damage for throwing people into walls at various speeds - calculate what height someone would fall from to reach that speed, or calculate damage per feet/second in speed based on the falling rules, for two options.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that if you throw a creature, you do just that.  You throw the creature however far you can and on the creature's turn it would function normally.  Even if you had feats that returned weapons and whatnot, I would argue that a thrown monster technically would not qualify as a weapon **that you are proficient with** and hence not be affected.  The GM bent the rules letting you throw him in the first place.  I would leave it at that.

Comment: no no no there are many feats that let you throw monsters it just very few of even deal with damage, races of stone have a few like fling ally and fling enemy. it just these feats dont cause damage to the thrown creature and that is what he changed because if you are thrown into a spike pit of off a cliff or even something simple as 20 feet into the air your should take damage from the landing

Comment: @b300 You're still not proficient with the "weapon" you're throwing, so the enchantment doesn't return it to you.

Comment: silversociety and @SevenSidedDie He did not actually state what feat he was using to throw the creature, so it's definitely a stretch to assume he is non-proficient. He specifically mentions that the feat allows him to treat the creature as a thrown weapon. If he doesn't take non-proficiency penalties, then the amulet should work. And in any event, there are other ways to apply *returning* to any weapon (lots of them, actually), without requiring proficiency, plus ways of getting proficiency in any weapon (*master's touch*, for one).

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules for this. The closest I can think of is to take the absence of any rule, and run it as normally as possible. We know the creature is now adjacent wherever you threw it, since it took damage/the creature it hit took damage. I suggest that, for its own turn, it runs its turn from that square normally. It only travels back to you just “before your next turn.”

This isn’t actually a rule. This is just extrapolation from the absence of specific rules for this case, with a dose of the KISS method. I wouldn’t even bother preventing the thrown creature from moving on its own turn, because that may be a pretty heavy nerf that’s not indicated in the rules. But then I am not much for simulationism.

And yes, there are plenty of ways to get *returning* (and *throwing*, for that matter) on creatures’ bodies. Kensai (*Complete Warrior*) is probably the least-obscure/most-straightforward way.